# How can I enable syntax highlighting, auto-complete etc. for GTK4 in python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ide, gtk

I'm using Visual Studio Code, and I am trying to develop my first application in GTK4 in python. So far, I managed to make some things, but everything without the IDE's help, because everything I try calling from GTK is white, and of type "Any".

```py
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "4.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk


class Window(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
  def __init__(self, app):
    #...
    hbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=20) # everything as Any type, and no help from the IDE with syntax highlighting or autocomplete
```

I tried looking for vs extensions with keywords such as "GTK" and "GTK Python", but none of them seems to be what I need.

So, is there any way to syntax highlight/auto-complete the GTK library in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simply to write:
`pip install pygobject-stubs`
as GTK is compiled dynamically and [this repo](https://github.com/pygobject/pygobject-stubs) does the job of assigning the correct class/function signatures

Answer (score 0):

Mostly vscode python extensions like

1. [vscode-python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)
2. [pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance)
3. [intellicode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode)

would `lint` and make `code completions` are you having these extensions installed please provide your `code` version and these `extensions` versions

Comment: Visual Studio Code: 1.74.1
vscode-python: v2022.20.1
pylance: v2022.12.20
intellicode: v1.2.29

This only happens in Gtk library, everything else is fine

Comment: Are you using any separate `python` environment for Gtk, if so verify the patch of python interpreter detected by `vscode-python` extension for example i have a python env which has django installed to it and if my `vscode-python` extension is detecting global python interpreter then code liniting can not happen

Comment: I'm not using a pyenv (yeah, I know I should, but for now everything is installed in the global env so I'll create one later), and I'm sure `Gtk` is installed, as `gi` and `gi.repository` are both highlighted